# How to understand scope/closure with recursion and helper function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

Here are examples with simple questions:

Example 1: Find maximum depth of binary tree.

I got the right answer but don't know why my original wrong answer is wrong.

Right answer:

```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
    if (root === null) return 0;
    var maxDepth = 1;
    maxDepth = maxDepthHelper(root, 1, maxDepth);
    return maxDepth;
};

function maxDepthHelper(tree, depth, maxDepth) {
    if (tree.left === null && tree.right === null) {
        maxDepth = depth > maxDepth ? depth : maxDepth;
        return maxDepth;
    }
    if (tree.left) {
    maxDepth = maxDepthHelper(tree.left, depth + 1, maxDepth);
    }
    if (tree.right) {
    maxDepth = maxDepthHelper(tree.right, depth + 1, maxDepth);
    }
    return maxDepth;
}
```

Wrong answer:

```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
    if (root === null) return 0;
    var maxDepth = 1;
    maxDepthHelper(root, 1, maxDepth);
    return maxDepth;
};

function maxDepthHelper(tree, depth, maxDepth) {
    if (tree.left === null && tree.right === null) {
        maxDepth = depth > maxDepth ? depth : maxDepth;
        return;
    }
    if (tree.left) {
        maxDepthHelper(tree.left, depth + 1, maxDepth);
    }
    if (tree.right) {
        maxDepthHelper(tree.right, depth + 1, maxDepth);
    }
}
```

It has something to do with me thinking the maxDepth should be changed by the helper function and ultimately when I return that it should return changed but it doesn't. It just returns 1 which is the original thing I assign it. But here in the example below, I am able to change a variable from the parent in the helper function, so what am I missing here?

Example 2: Given a binary search tree, write a function kthSmallest to find the kth smallest element in it.

Solution:

```
var kthSmallest = function(root, k) {
    let smallestArr = [];
    kthSmallestHelper(root, k, smallestArr);
    return smallestArr.pop()
};

function kthSmallestHelper(bst, k, array) {
    if (bst === null) return;
    kthSmallestHelper(bst.left, k, array);
    if (array.length === k) return;
    array.push(bst.val);
    kthSmallestHelper(bst.right, k, array);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `maxDepth` (lets call this the outer `maxDepth`) in the function `maxDepth` (unfortunate naming) stores a value (the number 1). When you call `maxDepthHelper(root, 1, maxDepth)`, the value 1 is passed in and stored in the local variable `maxDepth` inside `maxDepthHelper`. We can assign anything to the local `maxDepth`, but it won't affect the value stored in the outer `maxDepth`, because they are two different variables.

The variable `smallestArr` in the function `kthSmallest` stores a value; that value is a pointer (the memory location) to an empty array. When `kthSmallestHelper(root, k, smallestArr)` is called, just like before, that value (the pointer) is passed in and stored inside the local variable `array` in `kthSmallestHelper`. Effectively, now `array` and `smallestArr` both store a pointer (the memory location) to the same empty array. If we now do any assignment to `array`, like `array=['some new arr']`, the variable `smallestArr` won't get affected. But when you call a mutation method, like `array.push(bst)`, what happens is the Javascript engine looks at the pointer stored in `array`, and modifies the array stored at that memory location. Because `smallestArr` stores the pointer to this modified array, if you call `smallestArr.pop()`, the Javascript engine will pop the last item of the modified array.

The important thing to remember is anytime you write an expression like `let x = /* some array or object */`, an array/object is created, then a pointer to that array/object is stored in the variable. If you write `let x = /* some primitive value (like 3)*/`, the value 3 is directly stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the second program, `maxDepth` is a number and passed by value (copy), not by reference. The recursive calls are effectively no-ops, and their return values are immediately discarded. This is a common mistake for beginners that are learning how different variable types are passed from one function to another.

---

That said, recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding side effects like mutation and variable reassignment. You can simplify your `depth` program a lot -

```js
function depth(tree)
{ if (tree == null)
    return 0
  else
    return 1 + max(depth(tree.left), depth(tree.right))
}

function max (a, b)
{ if (a > b)
    return a
  else
    return b
}
```

An expression-based syntax is often preferred because expressions evaluate to values, whereas statements (like `if` and `return`) do not -

```
const depth = tree =>
  tree == null
    ? 0
    : 1 + max(depth(tree.left), depth(tree.right))

const max = (a, b) =>
  a > b
    ? a
    : b
```

---

Your `kthSmallest` program is more difficult but JavaScript's imperative-style generators make quick work of the problem. Mutation `k--` is used but cannot be observed from outside of the function -

```js
function *inorder (tree)
{ if (tree == null) return
  yield* inorder(tree.left)
  yield tree.val
  yield* inorder(tree.right)
}

function kthSmallest (tree, k)
{ for (const v of inorder(tree))
    if (k-- == 0)
      return v
}
```

The pure expression form of this program is slightly different -

```js
const inorder = tree =>
  tree == null
    ? []
    : [ ...inorder(tree.left), tree.val, ...inorder(tree.right) ]

const kthSmallest = (tree, k) =>
  inorder(tree)[k]
```

---

Here's a functioning demonstration -

```js
import { depth, fromArray, inorder, kthSmallest } from "./Tree"

const rand = _ =>
  Math.random() * 100 >> 0

const t =
  fromArray(Array.from(Array(10), rand))

console.log("inorder:", Array.from(inorder(t)))
console.log("depth:", depth(t))
console.log("0th:", kthSmallest(t, 0))
console.log("1st:", kthSmallest(t, 1))
console.log("2nd:", kthSmallest(t, 2))
console.log("99th:", kthSmallest(t, 99))
```

Output -

```
inorder: [ 12, 14, 25, 44, 47, 53, 67, 70, 85, 91 ]
depth: 5
0th: 12
1st: 14
2nd: 25
99th: undefined
```

Writing modules like `Tree` below is a good practice for separating concerns and organising your code -

```js
// Tree.js

const empty =
  null

const node = (val, left = empty, right = empty) =>
  ({ val, left, right })

const fromArray = (a = []) =>
  a.length < 1
    ? empty
    : insert(fromArray(a.slice(1)), a[0])

const insert = (t = empty, v = null) =>
  t === empty
    ? node(v)
: v < t.val
    ? node(t.val, insert(t.left, v), t.right)
: v > t.val
    ? node(t.val, t.left, insert(t.right, v))
: t

const depth = (tree = empty) => ...

const inorder = (tree = empty) => ...

const kthSmallest = (tree = empty, k = 0) => ...

export { depth, empty, fromArray, inorder, kthSmallest, node }
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const empty =
  null

const node = (val, left = empty, right = empty) =>
  ({ val, left, right })

const fromArray = (a = []) =>
  a.length < 1
    ? empty
    : insert(fromArray(a.slice(1)), a[0])

const insert = (t = empty, v) =>
  t === empty
    ? node(v)
: v < t.val
    ? node(t.val, insert(t.left, v), t.right)
: v > t.val
    ? node(t.val, t.left, insert(t.right, v))
: t

const inorder = (tree = empty) =>
  tree === empty
    ? []
    : [ ...inorder(tree.left), tree.val, ...inorder(tree.right) ]

const kthSmallest = (tree = empty, k = 0) =>
  inorder(tree)[k]

const depth = (tree = empty) =>
  tree == null
    ? 0
    : 1 + Math.max(depth(tree.left), depth(tree.right))

const rand = _ =>
  Math.random() * 100 >> 0

const t =
  fromArray(Array.from(Array(10), rand))

console.log("inorder:", JSON.stringify(Array.from(inorder(t))))
console.log("depth:", depth(t))
console.log("0th:", kthSmallest(t, 0))
console.log("1st:", kthSmallest(t, 1))
console.log("2nd:", kthSmallest(t, 2))
console.log("99th:", kthSmallest(t, 99))
```

Comment: No the answer you believe is wrong is not wrong. It doesn't overrwrite it because in the second call to the right side, the previous maxDepth is passed in as a parameter and it will only change maxDepth if it is bigger than that. That solution passed all test cases on leetcode (100s of test cases).

Comment: The answer to my question is that you cannot continually reassign a variable properly with the helper function as i was trying to do so. You can only mutate objects/arrays that way. Once i changed it to maxDepth = {value: 1}, and instead changed the value prop in helper, everything worked

Comment: @Kush, I was mistaken, you are correct. See the reassignment and mutation of `maxDepth` causes one's brain to get tied in knots. The reason the "wrong" program fails is because `Number` values are passed by value (copy), whereas `Object` values like the Array in the first program are passed by reference. Hopefully my answer shows you these kinds of problems can be avoided.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for telling me about the number being passed in by copy instead of by reference.